# How difficult would it be to flip an air return vent to the opposite wall?

Tags: hvac

We are starting to draw out some built-in shelves/cabinets/etc for our new home and unfortunately in two rooms we want to put large shelves there are air return vents in unideal places. These are both interior walls and on the opposite side of the wall there is empty space. Ideally, we could just cut open the wall on the other side of the air return, flip the adapter around, and drywall up the old hole, but I am not sure if that is possible. I have an old photo of one of them from before drywall was put up.

[image]

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Have you ever installed a dry wall (It is easy if you know how)? Cutting a hole will not do it. You have to remove the drywall to have access. Turing the vent arround means the room will no longer be controlled by AC

Comment: I can repair drywall. I don't think I'd have to remove much, just a little bit bigger than the register, right? The room still has supply vents, and the doorway to it has maybe an inch and a half gap under it, so air can still travel.

Comment: There is no good answer to "how easy".  If you are comfortable with cutting and replacing drywall, patching and painting, that part is easy.  If not, you can learn.  It's not hard to learn.   If you have an unfinished basement it should be very easy to turn this duct around, if not, it depends how comfortable you are with sheet metal work.  For an experienced installer it would be trivially easy.  It is certainly possible to do what you want.  We don't know your skills.

Comment: Often return vents are located centrally so they  serve multiple rooms.  If you move the return from a central location to one (on the opposite wall) where it is *one* of the rooms formerly served, you will upset the balance of air flow and your A/C will become less effective.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're going to leave ant room without a return grille, just going to swap the locations between two (or more) rooms.

Trying to remove that register and reorient it and reinstall it will be a major task.

So Don't. It's a tin box, you'll need stronger tools to cut a hole in the back of that than are needed for cutting drywall, but patching the old hole (in the register) is easy enough using some sheet metal, self-drilling screws, and metal tape.

Comment: Correct. The room still has supply registers and one is totally open and the other has a large gap under the door to it, so air can still travel between the two. Is reorienting hard just because more drywall needs to be cut? If I cut through the sheet metal, do I even need to patch the other side up with sheet metal, or will drywall do?

Comment: @Joe reorienting will be hard because the oval duct which goes through the floor (and is foamed in place) is crimped around the opening to the box.  To reorient, you would need to uncrimp, rotate the box, then re-crimp—would probably also need to tape because I doubt any retroactive crimping would be as good as factory.  Cutting a new hole and sealing up the old will be a heck of a lot easier. than reorienting.

Answer (score 1):

Thankfully you have a picture, so we know what are we dealing with.

For clarity reason let's call them room A (where the current vent is) and room B where it should go.

Since you do not want to remove the drywall but cut openings into it here is example how to do that.

It does not require cutting any drywalls.

Remove the vent grill in room A and use a drill with aprox 2 inches size. Since you have to drill through a thin sheet metal and drywall there are special drills for that.
It looks like this or similar:

[image: drill]

Drill as many as you can holes from room A to room B.

Get a pice of duct vents sheet metal cut to size to close the vent hole in room A, then cover with drywall.

Cover the room B with proper vent grill.

You might loose some air flow, but nothing drastic.

Answer (score -2):

This is something you need to discuss with your HVAC contractor. If you are doing the work you should consult with whoever designed the system.

Changing things could upset the balance of air flow and in a worst case scenario cause a failure of the inspection.

Have the conversation with the experts, rather than face a dilemma in the future.